# PHP query generator security update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use mysqli, I tried phpPDO, laravel, fluentPDO but my problem is always the updates.

I have strong security rules that must not be violated and in some tables some users are not allowed to update some fields, i think mysqli is not good but the question is..

How can I force an object passed by ajax json to only update some pre defined fields? I mean in the server side (PHP)

Do you have any other suggestion?...

I really don't like to work with mysqli but i can't see how to handle this problem using any of this query generators... This is painful because my queries get longer and I have to work on my own against sql injection

Comment: Use a white-list? Not sure what you are asking really.

Comment: Validate the incoming data, based on the logged-in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a framework like Laravel, look at the [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) restrictions in the ORM. You can limit which fields can be edited. You can also filter these before you update the model.

There's white-list and black-list options. Example from the documentation:

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
}
```

This isn't a query generator problem. This is something you address long before the query is generated.

Answer (score -1):

on the php side, have a whitelist, like:

```
if(!in_array($_POST['field'],array(
'every','field','this','user','is','allowed','to','edit'
))){
die("you do not have access to modify field ".htmlentities($_POST['field'],ENT_SUBSTITUTE));
}
$st=$db->prepare("UPDATE table SET ".$_POST['field']." = ?");
$st->execute(array($_POST['newData']));
```

and on the js side:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","?");
var fd=new FormData();
fd.set("newData","foobar");
fd.set("field","allowed");
xhr.send(fd);//no problem! "allowed" is in the whitelist!
fd.set("field","password");
xhr.send(fd);//error! you do not have access to modify field "password"!
```

Comment: @PeeHaa How the hell is this related to xss? and ofc this code should be ran after the user is authenticated... "How can I force an object passed by ajax json to only update some pre defined fields?", a whitelist will do exactly that

Comment: I didn't tell him how to insert the data ( though prepared statement or mysqli_real_escape_string), just how to make sure the user is allowed to edit the field :p also with the whitelist, he doesn't need to escape the field name.. its always valid or blocked by the whitelist check